# I can't multiple numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to find rp for each x but I'm having a hard time because matlab gives me this error

```
Error in enee_408e_hw2_pb1 (line 6)
rp=(z2*cos(t2)-z1*cos(x))/(z2*cos(t2)+z1*cos(x))
```

here is my code

```
x=0:.01:pi/2;
n2=1.7;
t2=asin(sin(x)/n2);
z1=377*cos(x);
z2=377\cos(x);
rp=(z2*cos(t2)-z1*cos(x))/(z2*cos(t2)+z1*cos(x));
```

I want to calculate rp for each angle from 0 to pi/2 and then plot it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every operation is perform on same cell in z1 and z2. Matlab/Ocatave calculate enquation based on variable's type. So if you put `*` between vectors it try to calculate cross product. Probably problem was `\`, I have no idea what Matlab tried to do with it. Adding `.` before operator change approach to more natural (for non mathematical folks) and multiply corresponding cells.
But still I'm not sure it this is what you expected

```
rp=(z2.*cos(t2)-z1.*cos(x))./(z2.*cos(t2)+z1.*cos(x));
```

Comment: awesome that worked! Thanks a lot for the help. If it is not so much trouble, can you tell me what does adding the `.` do?

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Vectors_and_matrices#Element_operations) you can find short explanation

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you using \ in this line?

```
z2=377\cos(x);
```

There is a difference between \ and / in MATLAB.

It is time to learn about the difference between ./ and .* versus / and * in MATLAB.

When you want element-wise operations, use the operators with a dot.

Comment: I want to divide I guess I should us `./` instead of \ ?

Comment: Yes. Use ./ to do an elementwise divide